# How to track the opening of a tab in a browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Some of the chrome extension opens third-party sites, I would like to determine which one. Maybe the window object contains information about what exactly opened the tab, but I could not find it. Or maybe there are other options?

Tried to find information about the open tab in the window object through devtools.

Comment: Disable one by one and see if it helps?

Comment: Well, I would do so, but the opening of the tab happens every few days. So it can be a long ...

Comment: Search for the URL in Github / Gitlab. A lot of extensions are open source

Comment: I have the same problem. My perspective to solve this problem is :
Go to extensiions page then click to cookies link (which is blue under the identiy) . When I click blue link devtools open. I write "window.open("https://www.google.com");"  to the console without double quotes. If you can't open a new vindow there is no need to delete this extension. 
By the way it is not a certain solution.